# How to get the selected Order(s) so i can use them for building a form in custom grid?

Tags: module, magento2.2, adminhtml, uicomponent, massaction

I am new to Magento and development in in general. I am working on a custom module. I did some tutorials and a lot of searching to help me get where i am. But now I have the feeling I am lost completely.

> My biggest problem right now is how to use the selected orders from the Order Grid so i get a (form) row for each of the selected orders in my Custom Grid.

What I want:

Get the selected orders:
[image]

and build a custom grid with those id's so I can save it in my custom table.
[image]

What I have:

1. module.xml

in: Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
</config>
```

2. registration.php
   in Vendor/Module/Registration.php

   ```
   <?php
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Vendor_Modul',
   __DIR__
   );
   ```
3. routes.xml
   in Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
      <router id="admin">
         <route id="vendor" frontName="vendor">
            <module name="Vendor_Packs"/>
         </route>
      </router>
   </config>
   ```

4 Install schema

in Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallSchema

```
     <?php
     namespace Vendor\Magento2\Setup;


     use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


     class InstallSchema implements  InstallSchemaInterface
     {
         /**
          * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
          * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
          * @throws \Zend_Db_Exception
          */
         public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
         {
             $setup->startSetup();

             try {

                 $tableShipment = $setup->getConnection()->newTable(
                     $setup->getTable('vendor-module_shipment')
                 )->addColumn(
                     'entity_id',
                     Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                     10,
                     array(
                         'identity' => true,
                         'unsigned' => true,
                         'nullable' => false,
                         'primary' => true,
                     ),
                     'Entity Id'
                 )->addColumn(
                     'magento_order_id',
                     Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                     10,
                     array(
                         'unsigned' => true,
                         'nullable' => true,
                     ),
                     'Magento Order Id'
                 )->addColumn(
                     'magento_shipment_id',
                     Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                     10,
                     array(
                         'unsigned' => true,
                         'nullable' => true,
                     ),
                     'Magento Shipment Id'
                 )->addColumn(
                     'packs_shipment_id',
                     Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                     10,
                     array(
                         'unsigned' => true,
                         'nullable' => true,
                     ),
                     'Vendor Shipment Id'
                 )->addIndex(
                     $setup->getIdxName(
                         'vendor-module_labels',
                         array(
                             'magento_order_id'
                         )),
                     array(
                         'magento_order_id'
                     ))->setComment('Vendor Shipment Label');

             } catch (\Zend_Db_Exception $e) {

             }

    $setup->getConnection()->createTable($tableLabels);
```

5. Resource model

in Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Shipment.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

    use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

    class Shipment extends AbstractDb
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {

            $this->_init('vendor_module_shipment', 'entity_id');
        }
    }
```

6. Collection
   in Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Shipment\Collection.php

   ```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Shipment;

    use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
    use Vendor\Module\Model\Shipment;
    use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Shipment as ShipmentResource;

    class Collection extends AbstractCollection
    {
        protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';

        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init(Shipment::class, ShipmentResource::class);

        }
    }
   ```

7 Model
in Vendor/Module/Model/Shipment

```
     <?php

     namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

     use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

     class Shipment extends AbstractModel
     {
         protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_module_shipment';

         protected function _construct()
         {
             $this->_init(\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Shipment::class);
         }
     }
```

8. Index controller

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

   use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

   class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
   {
       public function execute()
       {
             return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
       }
   }
   ```
9. Massaction in; Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

   ```
   <massaction name="listing_massaction">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.ids</item>
               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/massactions</item>
               <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
           </item>
       </argument>
       <action name="shipment">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="config" xsi:type="array" >
                   <item name="type" xsi:type="string">extension_id</item>
                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Voormelden &amp; Magento verzending aanmaken</item>
                   <item name="url" xsi:type="string">/admin/vendor/shipment/new</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
       </action>
   </massaction>
   ```

which sends my to

10. Controller in; Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/NewAction.php

    ```
     <?php

     namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment;

     use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
     use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
     use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
     use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
     use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;

     class NewAction extends Action
     {

     /**
      * @var \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter
      */
      protected $filter;

      /**
       * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
       */
      protected $_collectionFactory;

      public function __construct(
          Context $context,
          Filter $filter,
          CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
      ) {
          $this->filter = $filter;
          $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
          parent::__construct($context);
      }

      public function execute()
      {
          $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
          $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();

          $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Een totaal van %1 order(s) staan klaar om worden voorgemeld'   , $collectionSize));

          return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
      }
    }
    ```

I used massDelete as example and can get the collection and can var_dump it. But don't know how to use within the grid it directs me to(to a testform for saving single entry to custom database).

11. I also have a form for a single entry to my custom table. just for testing. In the end product this section should look like the 2nd picture above this page.

In Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/vendor_shipment_form.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_shipment_form.vendor_shipment_form_data_source</item>
                 <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_shipment_form.vendor_shipment_form_data_source</item>
             </item>
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
             <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
                 <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
             </item>
             <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                     <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                     <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/save</item>
                 </item>
             </item>
         </argument>
         <dataSource name="vendor_shipment_form_data_source">
             <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                 <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider</argument>
                 <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_shipment_form_data_source</argument>
                 <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
                 <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">colli</argument>
                 <argument name="collectionFactory" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Shipment\CollectionFactory</argument>
                 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor/shipment/save"/>
                     </item>
                 </argument>
             </argument>
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
                 </item>
             </argument>
         </dataSource>
         <fieldset name="general">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
                 </item>
             </argument>
             <field name="magento_order_id">
                 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order id</item>
                         <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                         <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                         <item name="default" xsi:type="string">10000036</item>
                     </item>
                     <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                     </item>
                 </argument>
             </field>
             <field name="colli">
                 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                         <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Colli</item>
                         <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                         <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                         <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                     </item>
                 </argument>
             </field>
         </fieldset>
     </form>
```

and the save controller that saves to the custom table.

13. Save controller, for saving a single entry in the custom table.

in Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Shipment/Save.php

```
     namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment;

     use Vendor\Module\Model\ShipmentFactory;
     use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

     class Save extends Action
     {
         private $shipmentFactory;

         public function __construct(
             Action\Context $context,
             ShipmentFactory $shipmentFactory
         ) {
             $this->shipmentFactory = $shipmentFactory;
             parent::__construct($context);
         }

         public function execute()
         {
             $this->shipmentFactory->create()
                 ->setData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue()['general'])
                 ->save();
             return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('vendor/index/index');
         }
      }
```

di.xml
in Vendor/Module/etc

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
         <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
     <!--         <arguments>
                 <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="confirm_status" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_shipment.confirm_status</item>
                     <item name="confirm_date" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_shipment.confirm_date</item>
                 </argument>
             </arguments>
      -->    </virtualType>
         <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
             <arguments>
                 <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="vendor_shipments_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Shipment\Grid\Collection</item>
                 </argument>
             </arguments>
         </type>
         <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Shipment"/>
         <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ShipmentRepository"/>
     </config>
```

And code to leftjoin sales_order table with that table. Now in Vendor/Module/Block, but not sure yet where to place this code in the end product.

```
     namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

     use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
     use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
     use Vendor\Module\Model\ShipmentFactory;
     use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

     class Shipment extends Template {

         protected $_shipmentModelFactory;
         protected $_resource;

         public function __construct(
             Context $context,
             ShipmentFactory $shipmentModelFactory,
             ResourceConnection $Resource
         ) {
             $this->_shipmentModelFactory = $shipmentModelFactory;
             $this->_resource = $Resource;

             parent::__construct($context);
         }

         protected function _prepareLayout()
         {
             $text = $this->getJoinData();
             $this->setText($text);

         }

         public function getJoinData(){
             $collection = $this->_shipmentModelFactory->create()->getCollection();
             $sales_order = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order');

             $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('order' => $sales_order),
                 'main_table.magento_order_id = order.increment_id');


             foreach ($collection as $item){
                 print_r($item->getData());
             }
             exit();
         }

     }
```

*If there is additional information you need to answer my question, say so and I update my question accordingly. Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Can you post your complete module?

Comment: @SukumarGorai Not the complete module but I tried to include the most important files. I  touched the max length of the post. In # 11  left out some columns.  If you want me to include more tell me.